# How to add a condition to toggleState?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the state of the `confirm` button conditionally, and I would like to keep it disabled as long as `length(input$id)>2` (but I might decide to add multiple conditions later on).

I did a few attempts,and I would appreciate if you could give some feedbacks on why they are not working properly.

First, the **ui.R** which is invariant for all the attempts:

```
library(shinyjs)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
          useShinyjs(),           
          fluidRow(
            column(5, offset = 3,
                   titlePanel("Consent form"),
                   consentForm
            )),    
          fluidRow(
            column(6, offset = 4,
                   div(
                     textInput(   "id",  "LSU ID", ""),
                     textInput(   "age",     "Age", ""),
                     selectInput( "gender",  "Select your gender", c("", "Male", "Female")),
                     actionButton("confirm", "Submit", class='btn-primary')
                   ))
          )
        ))
```

**1st server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    toggleState("confirm", condition = length(input$id)>2)
  })

})
```

**2nd server.R**

The issue here comes probably from my misinterpretation of the term "invalidate". In fact the second element of `observeEvent` is

> The expression to call whenever eventExpr is invalidated.

I thought "invalidate" meant "evaluated to `FALSE`", but apparently is not. Could anybody confirm?

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(length(input$id)>2, {
    toggleState("confirm")
  })
 })
```

**3rd attempt**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$id, {
    if (length(input$id)>2) {
    enable("confirm")
    } else {
      disable('confirm')
    }
  })
 })
```

Comment: I think you just need `nchar(input$id) > 2` instead of `length`.

Comment: @alistaire Really embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: No, it isn't embarrassing :)